# How to change linux default scheduling method

Tags: debian, jenkins, task-scheduler

I've a jenkins server and running a lot of CPU bound compilations. I want to change the scheduler from SCHED_NORMAL to SCHED_BATCH. I know it can be done with chrt but I want the system to use it by default for all jenkins jobs (and perhaps all processes on the system).

How can I set SCHED_BATCH to be the default?

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the systemd unit which starts Jenkins to set the CPU scheduling policy, using [`CPUSchedulingPolicy=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#CPUSchedulingPolicy=).

> Sets the CPU scheduling policy for executed processes. Takes one of `other`, `batch`, `idle`, `fifo` or `rr`. See sched_setscheduler(2) for details.

So you might create a drop-in for your Jenkins systemd service with a path such as `/etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d/scheduler.conf`:

```
[Service]
CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch
```